# Querying an entity on a recursive relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to query a recursive relationship in D2 for all fields that don't have a related element specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT c FROM RecursiveEntity c WHERE p.parent IS NULL
```